# React router dom - Navigate to urls with special characters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Currently I started a project in react, using react router dom v6
I try to add special characters such as '?' in the url, but I guess there is a mistake I'm doing, because it redirects to an empty page.

So my question is, can I create any page using an url with special characters (e.g. /cars?search)? If that's the case, how can I do that?

And another question is if I can use that type of urls, can I add params to it (e.g. /cars?search=toyota)? How can I do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to include the question mark in the URL as a normal character instead of marking the start of a query string, you should encode it as `%3F` (or ideally encode the whole string using [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)).

Comment: With `"/cars?search"` `"?search"` is still just a queryString. RRD doesn't consider the queryString for any part of the URL path matching and rendering. Do you have a more discrete example for what you are trying to do? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't use non-alphanumeric characters in the URL. Some characters like ?, = &, /,  have special meanings in URLs. ? used for query